# How to center a listing?

Tags: listings, horizontal-alignment

I'm trying to get some console output in my homework. I put it in a listings environment but I want it to be centered horizontally on the page. 
The only thing I get centered is the caption ;-/

```
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\begin{center}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Ausgabe des C-Programms},label={ggt_c_ausgabe}]
a  |  b  |  q  |  u  |  s  |  v  |  t  
----------------------------------------
78 |  21 |   1 |     |   1 |   1 |  -1 
21 |  15 |   3 |   1 |  -3 |  -1 |   4 
15 |   6 |   1 |  -3 |   4 |   4 |  -5 
 6 |   3 |   2 |   4 | -11 |  -5 |  14 
 3 |     |   2 | -11 |  26 |  14 | -33 
----------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I know some strange solutions involving saving the content temporary to a box and then determing the text width.

The simplest solution is to use a tabular environment:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{lstlisting}[...]
...
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

However, this doesn't center the caption. Making the caption centering correctly above the listing requires another solution. We have to take the caption out of the listings environment; this is done by a figure (or another floating environment).

Here's a way to center both your listing and the caption:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}
                    % replace figurename with the text that should preceed the caption
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[thp] % the figure provides the caption
\centering          % which should be centered
\caption{Ausgabe des C-Programms}
\begin{tabular}{c}  % the tabular makes the listing as small as possible and centers it
\begin{lstlisting}[label={gtt_c_ausgabe}]
a  |  b  |  q  |  u  |  s  |  v  |  t
----------------------------------------
78 |  21 |   1 |     |   1 |   1 |  -1
21 |  15 |   3 |   1 |  -3 |  -1 |   4
15 |   6 |   1 |  -3 |   4 |   4 |  -5
 6 |   3 |   2 |   4 | -11 |  -5 |  14
 3 |     |   2 | -11 |  26 |  14 | -33
----------------------------------------
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer. You'd think if tabular can centre it then the `center` environment should be able to as well, wouldn't you. (N.B. that fancyvrb users can use `center` around a `BVerbatim` environment without the `tabular`.)

Comment: @Will, @Matten: I can't get this solution to work properly. The listing is centered, yes, but the caption then is completely off-center.

Comment: Agree, listing is fine, but caption goes crazy.

Comment: As this answer has already 10 upvotes (although it didn't really answer the question so far), I took the freedom to add your nice solution from your other answer, inserted it here and made it closer to the code of the OP. Hope you don't mind. I'd suggest you remove that other answer.

Comment: @Hendrik -- thank you, I deleted the other answer.

Comment: Setting the `frame=none` option on the listing breaks this for me. And without it, the listing is centered, but has a frame that is one page wide.

Comment: FYI this also works great with input files using lstinputlisting

Answer (score 19):

The `lstlisting` package only boxes the contents if it starts in horizontal mode (which is the reason why it boxes the contents in a `tabular`).

A solution is to coerce horizontal mode, but there's the added problem of setting the caption, which can be done with the help of `\captionof`, persuading LaTeX into thinking this is a listings and not a figure.

In order to have a key-value interface, I set up a new one that intercepts `caption` and `label`, while it passes every unknown option to `\lstset`. The only change is that a short caption should be specified as a value to `shortcaption` and not with the

```
caption=[short caption]{long caption}
```

format of `listings`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe} % just for testing
\usepackage{listings,caption,xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_listings_boxed_options_tl
\keys_define:nn { listings/boxed }
 {
  caption .tl_set:N = \l_listings_boxed_caption_tl,
  shortcaption .tl_set:N = \l_listings_boxed_shortcaption_tl,
  label .tl_set:N = \l_listings_boxed_label_tl,
  unknown .code:n =
          \tl_put_right:NV \l_listings_boxed_options_tl \l_keys_key_tl
          \tl_put_right:Nn \l_listings_boxed_options_tl { = #1 , },
 }
\box_new:N \l_listings_boxed_box

\lstnewenvironment{blstlisting}[1][]
 {
  \keys_set:nn { listings/boxed } { #1 }
  \exp_args:NV \lstset \l_listings_boxed_options_tl
  \hbox_set:Nw \l_listings_boxed_box
 }
 {
  \hbox_set_end:
  \cs_set_eq:cc {c@figure} {c@lstlisting}
  \tl_set_eq:NN \figurename \lstlistingname
  \tl_if_empty:NF \l_listings_boxed_caption_tl
   {
    \tl_if_empty:NTF \l_listings_boxed_shortcaption_tl
     {
      \captionof{figure}{\l_listings_boxed_caption_tl}
     }
     {
      \captionof{figure}[\l_listings_boxed_shortcaption_tl]{\l_listings_boxed_caption_tl}
     }
    \tl_if_empty:NF \l_listings_boxed_label_tl { \label{\l_listings_boxed_label_tl} }
   }
  \leavevmode\box_use:N \l_listings_boxed_box
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{blstlisting}[
  caption=Ausgabe des C-Programms,
  shortcaption=Ausgabe, % just for showing the syntax, it can be omitted
  label=ggt_c_ausgabe,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily, % just for testing the option is correctly passed
]
a  |  b  |  q  |  u  |  s  |  v  |  t  
----------------------------------------
78 |  21 |   1 |     |   1 |   1 |  -1 
21 |  15 |   3 |   1 |  -3 |  -1 |   4 
15 |   6 |   1 |  -3 |   4 |   4 |  -5 
 6 |   3 |   2 |   4 | -11 |  -5 |  14 
 3 |     |   2 | -11 |  26 |  14 | -33 
----------------------------------------
\end{blstlisting}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It would seem that nobody but you and me cares about this answer :)

Comment: @SeanAllred You are wrong ;)

Comment: What would need to be changed if the caption should be placed below the listing?

Comment: @cryingshadow Move the `\leavevmode` line just after `\hbox_set_end:`

Comment: Did you see Rupert's "answer" below?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'll look at it when it will be a question

Comment: Isn't it just a matter of using `\captionof{lstlisting}`?  (Why do you have `\captionof{figure}` in the first place?)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. To be honest, I don't remember.