# Center a Listing on page

Tags: listings, horizontal-alignment

I am trying to center a listing horizontally within a page.

So far I have tried defining the following macro:

```
\lstnewenvironment{snippet}[1][]
    {\centering \lstset{float=htpb,#1}} 
    {}
```

But it did not work.

I have read [this question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing), but I would prefer a solution that does not rely in figures or tables.

Answer (score 3):

only possible when you define a width for a minipage:

```
\lstnewenvironment{snippet}[1][]
    {\hfill\lstset{frame=single,#1}\minipage{0.6\linewidth}}
    {\endminipage\hfill\null}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is ot working, it gives a `! Emergency stop.` error and the resulting file does not contain the listing.

Comment: @Tiago: than give me a minimal example, which shows this error. For me it works!

Answer (score 3):

If you set the line width i.e. `\lstset{linewidth=0.6\textwidth}`and want that centered, you can use margins instead. i.e.:

```
\lstset{linewidth=\textwidth,
xleftmargin=0.2\textwidth,
xrightmargin=0.2\textwidth}
```

I usually use this method, but I haven't tried with the float= setting.