# How to center a lstlisting

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

I have the following problem. I want to center a listing, I tried this approach: [How to center a listing?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing)

It works but when I try to set frame or numbers specifically for each listing I get errors. Here´s the M(Not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[thp]
 \begin{tabular}{c}
  \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left] % Here lies the problem without the numbers=left it works
   My Code
  \end{lstlisting}
 \end{tabular}
 \centering
 \caption{Bla}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Is there another way to center the listings **and** captions or how could I fix this approach?

Comment: The listing environment inside the `tabular` looks odd to me. I'm not sure if this is the best option, but I would go for a `minipage` solution, along with the `caption` package or something like that.

Comment: @guillem : It sounded weird to me as well, but that's indeed the way suggested by the linked answer. The minipage being the first attempt of the asker of the linked question.

Comment: I think that the OP in the linked question did not get the listing centered because the width of the `minipage` used is equal to `textwidth`. The problem with `minipage`, of course, is to automatically determine the horizontal size of the listing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution involving a table does not work here probably because `lstlisting` uses itself a table or other kind of tabular to put the numbers on the listing.

So the required solution for this case involves to save the content of the listing into a box, and then use the width of that box to size a `\parbox` or `minipage`, and put the original box inside. This new box can be centered by usual methods.

The problem is that `lstlisting` environment is a "verbatim-like" environment, and putting this kind of environment inside a box causes some problems. Fortunately `fancybox` package provides the environment `Sbox` devised for this kind of cases.

So my proposed solution is:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{fancybox}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{CenteredBox}{% 
\begin{Sbox}}{% Save the content in a box
\end{Sbox}\centerline{\parbox{\wd\@Sbox}{\TheSbox}}}% And output it centered
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[thp]
\begin{CenteredBox}
  \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
  My Code
  Another line
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{CenteredBox}
\caption{Bla}
\end{figure}

\noindent X\hrulefill X\par % This is to see the page width

\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Note that numbers are not part of the box (they are typeset with some kind of `\llap`), so they are not taken into account to center it.

Comment: Perfect, only drawback is you still have to use figure to keep the caption in line, but I can work with that, hehe, thank you very very much. I also would like to mention tex.stackexchange is really a great place, always excellent an fast answers to any question you have on your mind you guys are great!

Comment: You are welcome! I dont understand your problem with the caption. Currently it is also centered. Did you wanted it left-aligned with the listing?

Comment: What I meant was it would have been optimal if you could use the listings caption like this \begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left,caption=Bla] inside the CenteredBox instead of the figure caption, but no problem it´s just a few lines more this way, as long as the output looks good I´m happy.