# Center caption in boxed listings object

Tags: listings, fancybox

I have put some pseudocode in a listings object, with a caption and box around it. I have used the fancybox solution to listings objects suggested here: [How to center a lstlisting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85489/how-to-center-a-lstlisting)

Everything is fine, except the caption isn't centered.

Here's the output:

[image: Output of listings object with non-centered caption]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left, numbersep=10pt, frame = single, framexleftmargin=17pt}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{CenteredBox}{% 
\begin{Sbox}}{% Save the content in a box
\end{Sbox}\centerline{\parbox{\wd\@Sbox}{\TheSbox}}}% And output it centered
\makeatother

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\begin{document}
\section{Chapter}
\begin{CenteredBox}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Cool code},label=cool,linewidth=6in]
validity_type <- 0,1,2
uid <- '00000'
start_date <- '2014-11-20 00:00:00'
end_date <- '2014-11-21 00:00:00'

sql_query <- "SELECT variable_1
         , variable_2
         , variable_3
         FROM prices
         WHERE validity_type = ",validity_type," AND
         uid = '",uid,"'
         GROUP BY variable_1, variable_2, variable_3
         HAVING from_ts >= '",start_date,"' AND from_ts < '",end_date,"'
         ORDER BY variable_1 ASC, variable_2 ASC")
\end{lstlisting}
\end{CenteredBox}

\end{document}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on here.  The first is that a normal `lstlisting` is left aligned.  In addition, the line numbering (normally) is left-lapped and thus protrudes into the left margin.  Finally, the OP's MWE arbitrarily chooses 6in as the listing linewidth, a number that is not intrinsically related to the `\textwidth`.

Without the use of the `CenteredBox` environment, the label is centered.  But, when the `lstlisting` box is centered, the label moves rightward with it.  It required two changes, both to bring the label back to the center, and indeed to center the box:

1. First, I made the caption centered, by adding space following the caption, as in `caption={Cool code\hspace{\dimexpr\textwidth-6in+2ex}}`.  The portion that is `\textwidth-6in` represents the difference between the text width and the specified `lstlisting` width, whereas the 2ex is my estimate as to the additional lapped width arising from the two-digit numbered labels on the left edge of the listing.
2. The other thing I did was to add the space `\hspace{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-3in+1ex}` to the end of the listing, so as to shift the listing leftward.  Note that this distance is exactly 1/2 of that added to the caption width.

---

```
\documentclass[paper=a4, fontsize=11pt]{article} % A4 paper and 11pt font size
\usepackage[top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in, left=0.8in, right=0.8in]{geometry}

\usepackage{fourier} % Use the Adobe Utopia font for the document
\usepackage[english]{babel} % English language/hyphenation

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{numbers=left, numbersep=10pt, frame = single, framexleftmargin=17pt}

\usepackage{fancybox}
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{CenteredBox}{% 
\begin{Sbox}}{% Save the content in a box
\end{Sbox}\centerline{\parbox{\wd\@Sbox}{\TheSbox}}}% And output it centered
\makeatother

\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows customizing section commands
\allsectionsfont{\centering \normalfont\scshape} % Make all sections centered, the default font and small caps

\begin{document}
\section{Chapter}
\noindent\rule{.5\textwidth}{2pt} this line is .5 textwidth

\begin{CenteredBox}
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Cool code\hspace{\dimexpr\textwidth-6in+2ex}},%
   label=cool,linewidth=6in]
validity_type <- 0,1,2
uid <- '00000'
start_date <- '2014-11-20 00:00:00'
end_date <- '2014-11-21 00:00:00'

sql_query <- "SELECT variable_1
         , variable_2
         , variable_3
         FROM prices
         WHERE validity_type = ",validity_type," AND
         uid = '",uid,"'
         GROUP BY variable_1, variable_2, variable_3
         HAVING from_ts >= '",start_date,"' AND from_ts < '",end_date,"'
         ORDER BY variable_1 ASC, variable_2 ASC")
\end{lstlisting}
\hspace{\dimexpr.5\textwidth-3in+1ex}
\end{CenteredBox}

\medskip
\noindent\hrulefill\\
the above line is textwidth

\end{document}
```

[image]