# Listing has wrong numbering if used with separate caption

Tags: listings

I am using the listings package inside my document, and to use a footnote inside the caption of a listing I had to separate the `\caption` from the `\lstinputlisting`.

If I create the document now, the listing with the separate caption seems to follow a different numbering than the other ones - while the surrounding listings are "Listing 5.6" and "Listing 5.7" the one with the separate caption is called "Listing 1".

Here's the code I am working with (I dumbed it down a bit, still the exact same structure as in the document though):

```
% This listing is working just fine (called Listing 5.6 in the document).
\begin{lstfloat}
    \lstinputlisting[label=code:abort,caption={Workin caption here},captionpos=b]{Inhalt/Code/abort.js}
\end{lstfloat}

Here is some text to talk about the listing...

% This listing is suddenly called Listing 1
\begin{lstfloat}
    \lstinputlisting[label=code:shell]{Inhalt/Code/shell.sh}
    \caption[Manipulation und Abfrage der Daten mithilfe von cURL]{Manipulation und Abfrage der Daten mithilfe von cURL\protect\footnotemark}
\end{lstfloat}

\footnotetext{\url{https://curl.haxx.se/}}

% This listing is working file as well (called Listing 5.7 in the document)
\begin{lstfloat}
    \lstinputlisting[label=code:connect,caption={Another working caption},captionpos=b]{Inhalt/Code/connect.js}
\end{lstfloat}
```

I am no LaTeX expert and I have no idea what is going wrong.

Comment: Floating the footnote text was the only solution I found online to handle the footnote inside the caption in the first place - and it does end up on the previous page. Apart from the numbering issue, do you have an idea on how to fix that?

EDIT:
I will try out putting the label below the caption and come back to you

EDIT:
The issue persists. Putting the label below the caption is _not_ the correct solution.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Just ommitting the footnote inside the caption? That does not seem like a constructive solution, tbh.

Comment: Yes. And I do not want to discuss this. I am searching for a solution of the problem, not for advice on how to write a document.

Answer (score 1):

You should read the documentation of `listings`.

I ***guess*** that `lstfloat` has been taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/354023/4427

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.sh}
echo "Hello World"
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}

\newfloat{lstfloat}{htbp}{lop}
\floatname{lstfloat}{Listing}
\newcommand{\mylistoflistings}{\listof{lstfloat}{List of Listings}}
\AtBeginDocument{\counterwithin{lstlisting}{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{lstfloat}[!hp]
    \lstinputlisting[label=code:abort,caption={Workin caption here},captionpos=b]{\jobname.sh}
\end{lstfloat}

Here is some text to talk about the listing...

\begin{lstfloat}[!hp]
    \lstinputlisting[
      label=code:shell,
      captionpos=b,
      caption={%
       [Manipulation und Abfrage der Daten mithilfe von cURL]%
       {Manipulation und Abfrage der Daten mithilfe von cURL\protect\footnotemark}},
    ]{\jobname.sh}
\end{lstfloat}

\footnotetext{\url{https://curl.haxx.se/}}

Here is some text to talk about the listing...

\begin{lstfloat}[!hp]
    \lstinputlisting[label=code:connect,caption={Another working caption},captionpos=b]{\jobname.sh}
\end{lstfloat}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You already proposed this solution in the comments you provided above and then deleted after I told you that this is _not_ the solution. I do not know how to make it more clear besides telling you a third time: This does _not_ work.

Comment: @ThomasPötzsch I assumed you defined `lstfloat` in a *correct* way; apparently you don't. Anyway, there is no need to specify separately the `\caption`. The current version *does* work, but I had to guess something about `lstfloat`.