# Center a Listing

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings

What is *a simple way* to make a `lstlisting` centered? Like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
    fancyvrb=true,%
    captionpos=b, % captions at the bottom
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={I want to be centered},label={lst:label}]
object Stream {
  def cons[A](hd: A, tl:...
     def head = hd
     lazy val tail = tl
     ...
  }
}
abstract class Stream[A] {
  def head: A
  def tail: Stream[A]
  def take(n: Int): Stream[A]
  def foreach(fun: A...
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Note**: Putting it [inside a `tabular` inside a `figure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106419/center-latex-lstlisting) neither works (captions are screwed), nor does it fall under my idea of *simple*. The other answer in that question (using `\begin{center}`) also doesn't work for me. Also [taking the caption out of listing and into the figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing#5822) is not an option, because I am precisely using `lstlisting` because I want separate enumerations for separate table of figures versus table of listings.

If this can be done in a macro and without corner case, I am happy to have another macro. Thanks!

Comment: The following [works](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk0c2.png): `\begin{center} \begin{varwidth}{\linewidth} \begin{lstlisting} ... \end{lstlisting} \end{varwidth} \captionof{lstlisting}{I want to be centered\label{lst:label}} \end{center}` (adding the [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and [`varwidth`](http://ctan.org/pkg/varwidth) packages to your preamble).

Comment: Perfect, can you post that as an answer? BTW `captionof` doesn't work here, probably needs another package, but the regular `lstlisting` options for caption and label still work fine.

Comment: Damn. It works isolated, but not in my thesis. Shows up left aligned :-(

Comment: It seems that `\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}` has wrong information. I can find a concrete value, like `\begin{varwidth}{10cm}` for which it works. Why might `varwidth` be broken?

Comment: I found the [problem I am seeing](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142476/caption-package-destroys-center-varwidth)

Comment: As you can see, I put the `\caption` outside the `varwidth` environment, just like in @egreg's answer... is that not sufficient?