# Caption package destroys center/varwidth

Tags: horizontal-alignment, listings, captions, varwidth

I have received a [wonderful comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142468/center-a-listing?#comment322298_142468) how to get listings centered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
%\usepackage[hang,small,it,hypcap=true]{caption}  % screw hypcap
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  fancyvrb=true,%
}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,%
    fancyvrb=true,%
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}%
\begin{lstlisting}[caption={I want to be centered},label={lst:label2}]
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type Tx     <: stm.Txn[S]
  type Var[A] <: stm.Var[S#Tx, A]
  type ID     <: stm.Identifier[S#Tx]
  type Acc
  ...
}
\end{lstlisting}\end{varwidth}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

So far so good:

[image]

If I add the `caption` package (uncomment in the example above) which I *must do* because a lot of stuff relies on it, the centering is destroyed:

[image]

I also found that adding the `showframe` package has the same problem, so perhaps the culprit is `center` or `varwidth` and not `caption`. How to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varwidth` is not able to cope with arbitrary contents and you get the warning

```
Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents
```

In these cases the environment becomes simply a `minipage` with the stated width. You can do with the caption outside the `lstlisting` environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
  hang,
  small,
  it,
  hypcap=true
]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  fancyvrb=true,
}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,
    fancyvrb=true,
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type Tx     <: stm.Txn[S]
  type Var[A] <: stm.Var[S#Tx, A]
  type ID     <: stm.Identifier[S#Tx]
  type Acc
  ...
}
\end{lstlisting}\end{varwidth}
\captionof{lstlisting}{I want to be centered}\label{lst:label2}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Watch out about possible page breaks between the listing and the caption. A float would be better; `figure` (with `\captionof{lstlisting}`) would be good.

Comment: Thanks. I have a problem with this solution when adding the `color` package. It seems to break the alignment (see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196237/adding-color-package-destroys-listing-centering) question). I found another variant which I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\lstset{xleftmargin=0.18\textwidth,xrightmargin=0.18\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type Tx     <: stm.Txn[S]
  type Var[A] <: stm.Var[S#Tx, A]
  type ID     <: stm.Identifier[S#Tx]
  type Acc
  ...
}
\end{lstlisting}
\captionof{lstlisting}{Type members of the system abstraction}\label{lst:scala_system_decl}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]