# Adding color package destroys listing centering

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, listings, color, varwidth

I am using @egreg's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142476/caption-package-destroys-center-varwidth) to make listings centered:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[
  hang,
  small,
  it,
  hypcap=true
]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  fancyvrb=true,
}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,
    fancyvrb=true,
    captionpos=b
}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\begin{lstlisting}
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type Tx     <: stm.Txn[S]
  type Var[A] <: stm.Var[S#Tx, A]
  type ID     <: stm.Identifier[S#Tx]
  type Acc
  ...
}
\end{lstlisting}\end{varwidth}
\captionof{lstlisting}{I want to be centered}\label{lst:label2}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This looks ok at first:

[image]

**However**: Something odd happens. When I add the `color` package, the alignment is broken:

```
\usepackage{color}  % add somewhere to above document
```

Result:

[image]

Please help. I need to include the color package. How can it break the alignment?

Comment: One workaround (until someone answers) is `\begin{varwidth}{.65\linewidth}`.  Of course, you would hate to have to do that with a different multiplier for every listing.

Comment: I think that `listings` wrongly sets colors without using the appropriate interface, so it does `\normalcolor` in a place that breaks `varwidth`. If I remove `\normalcolor` from `\lst@DeInit`, there is no problem with the code, but I'm afraid this could cause color leakage.

Comment: This looks like a bug, which should be reported to the current maintainer of `listings`.

Answer (score 1):

This adds an extra brace group to make the box setting in `\lst@DeInit` "color safe" then removes `\normalcolor` as egreg mentioned in comments. Seems to work on this example..

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[
  hang,
  small,
  it,
  hypcap=true
]{caption}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  fancyvrb=true,
}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\linespread{0.94}\ttfamily,
    fancyvrb=true,
    captionpos=b
}
\makeatletter
\def\lst@DeInit{%
    \lst@XPrintToken \lst@EOLUpdate
    \global\advance\lst@newlines\m@ne
    \lst@ifshowlines
        \lst@DoNewLines
    \else
        \setbox\@tempboxa\vbox{{\lst@DoNewLines}}%extra group for color
    \fi
    \lst@ifdisplaystyle \par\removelastskip \fi
    \lsthk@ExitVars\everypar{}\lsthk@DeInit\normalbaselines
    \lst@MakeCaption b%
    \lst@ifbox
        \egroup $\hss \egroup
        \vrule\@width\lst@maxwidth\@height\z@\@depth\z@
    \else
        \lst@ifdisplaystyle
            \par\penalty-50\vspace\lst@belowskip
        \fi
    \fi
    \ifx\lst@multicols\@empty\else
        \def\lst@next{\global\let\@checkend\@gobble
                      \endmulticols
                      \global\let\@checkend\lst@@checkend}
        \expandafter\lst@next
    \fi
    \ifx\lst@float\relax\else
        \expandafter\lst@endfloat
    \fi
    \endgroup}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\tracingmacros2
\begin{lstlisting}
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type Tx     <: stm.Txn[S]
  type Var[A] <: stm.Var[S#Tx, A]
  type ID     <: stm.Identifier[S#Tx]
  type Acc
  ...
}
\end{lstlisting}\end{varwidth}
\captionof{lstlisting}{I want to be centered}\label{lst:label2}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```