# Text outside tbox

Tags: captions, listings, tcolorbox

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{lstlisting} [caption = {C Code}, captionpos=b, label = {Listing3}, abovecaptionskip=12pt]
int a ,b;
int value = 20;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

I am using the above code for listing. In current situation, caption is written inside the tcolorbox. I want to write it outside the box. what command I should add ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436) That you've no answer after two days could be because you used the wrong tag. But it would also help a lot, if you'd show a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/277964) instead of a code snippet only. And what do you mean with “outside the box”? Completely outside or something like a header box as shown in chapter 17 of the `tcolorbox` manual?

Comment: Just a hint https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142476/caption-package-destroys-center-varwidth/142481#142481

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is the one you expects:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf,font=footnotesize]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain} 

\usepackage{capt-of}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{lstlisting} [ label = {Listing3}, abovecaptionskip=12pt]
int a ,b;
int value = 20;
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tcolorbox}
 \captionof{lstlisting}[C Code]{C Code}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you are not provided full `MWE`, so I used the standard `book` class file

Comment: Thanks. It works.  In order to ref this list , I am using \ref{Listing3}, means lable. First time it picks exact reference ,while refering second list by new label .Then there is label of first list (not considering new label) 2)\captionof{lstlisting}[C Code]{C Code} means caption , but why it appears twice? 3) For new caption, I have written \begin{lstlisting} [ label = {Listing4}, abovecaptionskip=12pt]    ......as \captionof{lstlisting}[C++ Code]{C++ Code}