# Float numbering does not include chapter when using \DeclareNewTOC

Tags: floats, numbering, captions, koma-script

I use the `\DeclareNewTOC` command from the KOMA classes because it automatically produces hanging indents for the caption, same as the builtin floating environments like `figure`. However, unlike `figure`, the number of my newly defined float does not include the chapter number. The `level` option that is mentioned in the KOMA manual does not seem to do anything.

How can I fix it to show e.g. 1.1? Alternative solutions that produce the same result are also welcome.

[image: Wrong numbering]

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrreprt}
\DeclareNewTOC[
    float, type=floatlisting, types=floatlistings,
    %level=2, % Doesn't do anything
    name=Listing, listname={List of Listings}
]{lol}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Topic}
\begin{floatlisting}[h]
Foo
\caption{Some really long caption that leads to a line break.}
\end{floatlisting}
\begin{figure}[h]
Foo
\caption{Some really long caption that leads to a line break.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: btw: package `listings` has it's own implementation of captions.

Comment: Yes, you are right of course. But when using the `[float,caption=Foo]` options on the `lstlisting` environment, I can't center the code (see this question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the option `counterwithin=chapter`.

```
\documentclass[paper=A6]{scrreprt}
\DeclareNewTOC[
    float, type=floatlisting, types=floatlistings,
    counterwithin=chapter,%<-%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    name=Listing, listname={List of Listings}
]{lol}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Topic}
\begin{floatlisting}[h]
    Foo
    \caption{Some really long caption that leads to a
    line break.}
\end{floatlisting}
\begin{figure}[h]
    Foo
    \caption{Some really long caption that leads to a
    line break.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't really know how I did miss that in the manual... `-.-`

Comment: Of by the way, the key is called `counterwithin`, not `counterwith`. I see that it is correct in the code but not in the opening text.

Comment: @Fritz I was in a hurry, thanks for fixing this.