# Force figure to be a listing

Tags: floats, listings

To center my listings on the page I followed [a tutorial on tex.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing).com and that resulted in the following code:

```
{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}
\begin{figure}[H] % the figure provides the caption
  \centering          % which should be centered
  \caption{Example of factorial using the SAL actor language.}
  \begin{tabular}{c}
\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle= \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    belowcaptionskip=0em,
    language=SAL,
    label={lst:salfactorial}]
def Factorial() [val, cust]
    become Factorial() ||
    if val = 0
        then send [1] to cust
            else let cont = new FactorialCont(val, cust)
                in send [val - 1, cont] to self
end def

def FactorialCont(val, cust) [arg]
    send [val * arg] to cust
end def

// Top level expression
let x = [recep] new Factorial()
    in send [5] to x
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}}
```

The problem with this approach is that I do have a listing now (when I use `\autoref` it shows `Listing`) but it uses the counter for Figures.

As a result, the above shown figure/listing is numbered `Listing 2.1`, but an actual listing above is also printed as `Listing 2.1`.

I don't want to use the same counter for *all* Figures and Listings, just make this figure use the Listing counter. So if I would have actual figures they would be numbered 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3. If I had two actual Listings and one Listing inside a Figure (as shown above) they would be numbered Listing 1.1, 1.2 and 1.3.

### Minimal Example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{listings}
\title{Test}
\author{Christophe De Troyer}
\date{May 2015}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo}
{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Listing}
\begin{figure}[H] % the figure provides the caption
  \centering          % which should be centered
  \caption{Example of factorial using the SAL actor language.}
  \begin{tabular}{c}


\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle= \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    belowcaptionskip=0em,
    language=SAL,
    label={lst:salfactorial}]
first listing
\end{lstlisting}
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}}

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle= \footnotesize\ttfamily,
    belowcaptionskip=0em,
    language=SAL,
        caption={second listing},
    label={lst:second}]
second listing
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: …*or* you could read in §4.3 of the manual that you can provide `float` and `caption` options to the `lstlisting` environment directly. :) You may also be interested in `\lstset` as as to not repeat yourself (with `basicstyle`, `belowcaptionskip`, etc.). If you want it to stay put but have a caption/reference, I think you can just say give it a `caption`. By the way, you should link to this tutorial you found. It would appear that it needs to be corrected.

Comment: The caption would not be centered if I put it inside the listing, hence the enclosing figure defined the caption. I will read through the manual! Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Oh goodness, alright. Well, I'll be investigating a better way to center the caption :) Can you provide me a reference image for desired output? (Reference numbering notwithstanding.)

Comment: Take a look at [egreg's new answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245750/17423) to the linked question; it might solve your problem.

Comment: Any news here? Did you have a look at the linked answer?