# Overfull hbox when centering lstlisting (using tabular)

Tags: tables, listings

I would like to center code listings when they are narrower than the full page, but wrap them when they are not.

I am using a table to do so, following the advice from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/5822/90559). As `breaklines` is turned on, these lines are wrapped, so the result is displaying properly. However, when a line needs wrapping, it is emitting the warning of an overfull hbox.

The same pre-listing/post-listing code needs to be used regardless of whether it will wrap or not.

This means that the output is correct, I would only like to avoid the overfull hbox warnings. How can I avoid these warnings?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\center\tabular{c}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
# narrow
# should be centered
\end{lstlisting}
\endtabular\endcenter

\center\tabular{c}
\begin{lstlisting}[breaklines]
1 abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc 2
\end{lstlisting}
\endtabular\endcenter
\end{document}
```

**Current output** (should not change)

[image: Output]

**Current log** (should be removed)

Overfull \hbox (141.00484pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--17

Comment: You shouldn't put such a listing in a c-type column.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what method would you suggest for centring a listing then?

Comment: @CharlieHarding: Why do you place the `lstlisting` inside of the `tabular`? Just to horizontally center the `lstlisting? If that's the case, a simple `center` environment should be sufficient. However, please note that there is no point in centering something that is as wide as the textwidth anyways. Please clarify.

Comment: @leandriis yes, to horizontally center it. Some of my listings are wide enough to need wrapping, whereas others are narrower and so need wrapping. Simply using `\center` doesn’t work as a narrower listing will still take up `\textwidth`. The answer I was following was this one: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5818/how-to-center-a-listing/5822#5822

Comment: @leandriis I have edited the question to hopefully clarify this